# Convert confirm() to Bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code which opens a normal JS `confirm()` dialog at the top of the page when I click on the delete record button.

I want to have the same thing happen using a Bootstrap modal or jQuery confirmation dialog modal.

```html
<a id="deleteCode" class="dTButtons" branchcode="val.BranchCode">
  <span id="delete">
    <img src="../Images/fi-rr-trash.svg"/>
  </span>
</a>
```

```js
$(document).on("click", "#deleteCode", function() {
  var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
  if (r == true) {
    var mode = "D";
    var branchcode = parseInt($(this).attr('branchcode'));
    DeleteBranch(branchcode, mode);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

function DeleteBranch(branchcode, mode) {
  var obj = {
    BranchCode: branchcode,
    Mode: mode
  }
  funCallAjax(savebranchsuccess, savebranchsuccess, '/api/mastersapi/DeleteBranch', obj, "POST");
}
```

Comment: There is a modal dialog built directly in to Bootstrap. The documentation shows examples and has comprehensive instructions on how to use it: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/

Comment: If you want to use custom alert boxes, you can use SweetAlerts([SWAL](https://sweetalert.js.org)) library , Although if you want to stick to BS Modal please go with @RoryMcCrossan's suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace standard javascript confirm with Twitter Bootstrap's modal - who triggered it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139366/replace-standard-javascript-confirm-with-twitter-bootstraps-modal-who-trigger)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "#deleteCode", function () {
    //$('#deleteModal').modal().show();
    var txt;
    var codeid = parseInt($(this).attr('codeid'));
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Delete Record?',
        content: 'Are you sure You want to delete the record?',
        type: 'white',
        buttons: {
            ok: {
                text: "DELETE",
                btnClass: 'btn btn-danger',
                keys: ['enter'],
                action: function () {
                    DeleteZone(codeid);
                    $.alert({
                        title: 'Alert!',
                        content: 'Record Deleted successfully!',
                        confirm: function () {
                            tim
                            alert('Deleted Alert!');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            cancel: function () {
                console.log('the user clicked cancel');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The Perfect solution which I have implemented for my own above question, Jquery Modal Confirmation on Delete button click.

Answer (score 5):

With **ES6** and **BootStrap 5.1**

Just in plain Vanilla JS. Using promises.
Simulate bootstrap modal as native confirm() with the same behaviour

***Syntax***:

`result = await b_confirm(message)`

***Parameters***:

*message*: A string you want to display in the confirmation dialog.

***Return value***:

A boolean indicating whether OK (true) or Cancel (false) was selected

```js
(async() => {
  const result = await b_confirm('IT WILL BE DELETED')
  alert(result)
})()

async function b_confirm(msg) {
  const modalElem = document.createElement('div')
  modalElem.id = "modal-confirm"
  modalElem.className = "modal"
  modalElem.innerHTML = `
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
      <div class="modal-content">             
        <div class="modal-body fs-6">
          <p>${msg}</p>
          <p>Are you sure?</p>
      </div>    <!-- modal-body -->
      <div class="modal-footer" style="border-top:0px">             
        <button id="modal-btn-descartar" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
        <button id="modal-btn-aceptar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
  const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalElem, {
    keyboard: false,
    backdrop: 'static'
  })
  myModal.show()

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', response)

    function response(e) {
      let bool = false
      if (e.target.id == 'modal-btn-descartar') bool = false
      else if (e.target.id == 'modal-btn-aceptar') bool = true
      else return

      document.body.removeEventListener('click', response)
      document.body.querySelector('.modal-backdrop').remove()
      modalElem.remove()
      resolve(bool)
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This just helped me a tonne - but had one minor issue where a class of `modal-open` was added to the body to disable scrolling and never removed. Adding `myModal.hide()` fixed that. Probably just something that has been added to Bootstrap since this answer was added.